# Custom payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, module, payment-methods

Store process payment manually or over phone but needs to track what method used on order and reflect this on invoice.

When client checks out i need to show 4 radio buttons

```
- Credit Card 
- Check 
- Money Order 
- Cash
```

Then just track what option was selected on invoice, no need for extra fields or third party processors, how can i do it?

I tried to look for tutorial on how to create custom payment method, but its a nightmare most tutorials are for old versions and not compatible with 1.9, other tutorials even official ones are incomplete.

e.g. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

i followed this have payment method showing in admin, but not in front end. I assume from other tutorials that i need to specify **.phtml** to load somewhere in code but why its not in official tutorial?!

I am not trying to learn everything about Magento or MVC at this point just need quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Check this out, I think it does exactly what you need: https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_MultipleBankTransferPaymentMethods (see also my own question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86938/add-more-simple-payment-methods/86953#86953)