# Add more simple payment methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

We need to add quite a lot of payment methods that are really simple and require nothing beyond what the built-in "*Bank Transfer Payment*" method already offers, for example:

- Bank Transfer
- Prepayment
- In-store pickup

So now I'm looking for a way to "duplicate" the "*Bank Transfer Payment*" method so I can show all three (or even more) of the above options to the customer when they check out. They select one of the payment methods and submit their order, and nothing else has to happen.

Does anyone have any recommendations how I would go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is not considered self-promotion, but I have just created a new extension that adds four duplicates of the default "*Bank Transfer Payment*":

https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_MultipleBankTransferPaymentMethods

I will be using this on a new project now so the repository will be updated should I find any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the extension and renaming a hole bunch of `foobar` would be one way.

The EASIER way is to load the required extensions form the repository and use them.

Use:

`connect20/bankprepayment`

`spranks/store-pickup`

...

Have a look here: http://packages.firegento.com/ or here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/